# Split Common Neutral for DC Current

Tags: power, current, dc, circuit-common

I have a motorcycle headlamp that I am lighting outside of a motorcycle. It's a stage prop, I have the front end of a motorcycle built as my microphone stand. The bulb has hard set 3 terminals, two leads and 1 common out. I am wanting to put a blinker on one of the lights (high beam) and have a switch just for on and off on the other light (low beam).

I am wondering if I am running into a problem where the common terminal on the light comes out and I have to split the cable to run to the two negative terminals. Will the current split and distribute amongst the two? Will this work ok? I have the two power supplies to provide enough amps to run both of the lights. By the way, this is DC Current. Thanks so much for your help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f060SI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can one supply provide enough current for both connections?

Comment: When doing the math the circuit would pull more amps than just one of the supplies would provide. Thinking it would overtax it if it did even work.

Answer (score 3):

Your setup will work fine. [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_current_law_.28KCL.29) states that each supply will take back from the negative only as much current as they put out on the positive.

Comment: @willb41: Please mark the answer as accepted then.